# Redirecting incoming calls to different numbers depending on WiFi connectivity

Tags: applications, wi-fi, calls

Can we have an android application which will direct any incoming call to:

1. The cell number in case WiFi is disabled
2. Office extension number through Jabber client in case WiFi is connected (when I am in office, I want to receive calls on my extension instead of cell).

Is there any Jabber client is available which has such settings, or I need to develop an Android application (In java) which can achieve this?

Comment: This is a very particular case because not everybody which has a WiFi connection is necessarily in an office, so I think currently there is no app to achieve this. I might be wrong but I guess you'll have to develop that one.

Comment: Will Xabber be the suitable Jabber client for this?

Comment: Try with [Xabber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xabber.android), because is highly rated by users, although you should check out Cisco [Jabber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cisco.jabber) too.